# Hamburger menu doesn't open

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

```
       <a href="#"class="navbar-button" onclick="hideShow()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </a>

...
 </nav>
        <div class="little-menu">
            <ul class="little-menu-list">
                <li class="little-menu-list-general">General
                    <div class="little-menu-list-general-li">
                        <ol>
                            <li>Home</li>



    <script>
        function hideShow(){
            const getElement = document.querySelector('.little-menu');
            if(getElement.style.display=="none"){
                getElement.style.display == "block";
            }else{
                getElement.style.display == "none";
            }

        }
    </script>
```

This is how I made a hamburger menu but it's not open.

I wanted to make a front-aligned hamburger menu. However, when I click the button, the hamburger does not appear on my menu screen.

Comment: You're using `==` instead of `=` for assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is you are setting the variable with double equal signs, but that is for comparison, so you would use just one.

However, I would get used to using classes instead of changing the CSS in javascript. Using classes will give you more flexibility in the long run.

In my snippet, I'm toggling a class called active which will set the display to block. By default I give little-menu the display of none.

And for your button, I would use the button element and not anchor. You can still style the button element as needed. You just don't have to deal with preventing the default behavior of the link.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".navbar-button");
const getElement = document.querySelector('.little-menu');

btn.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
   getElement.classList.toggle("active")
});
```

```css
.little-menu{display:none;}
.little-menu.active{display:block;}
```

```html
<button class="navbar-button">X</button>
<div class="little-menu">OPEN!</div>
```